# Can you copy files with invalid filenames to ntfs and change the name automatically?

Tags: ntfs

I have a bunch of files spread over a lot of folders in an ext4 disk. Some of those files have illegal characters for ntfs (like `:` or `|` ) and so I get errors when I try to copy them to be seen in Windows.

Is there any tool that will let me copy the files and change the names as needed, or do I need to write my own?

Comment: The easiest approach would be to write your own. Make a list of all the illegal characters. Search and replace them in the file names.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/348482/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames for some solutions

Answer (score 6):

Check this answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/178025/linux-copy-to-fat32-filesystem-invalid-argument

In short, install `pax`:

```
sudo apt install pax
```

Now instead of doing:

```
cp -r sourcedir destdir
```

to copy a directory tree, you can instead run:

```
pax -rw -s '/[*?:]/_/gp' sourcedir destdir
```

This way `pax` will *rename* only the copies of the files when necessary.

Each `*` or `?` or `:` character will be replaced with a `_` character automatically.  This means it is potentially possible that multiple files will receive the same new name.

Answer (score 0):

#### Vanilla, CLI, one-liner

If you are in the source directory...

```
for a in *; cp -r "${a}" "/path/to/destination/$(echo ${a} | sed 's/[*?:]/_/g')"; done
```

For progress, you can add this line in the for-do loop:

```
echo Copying "${a} ..."
```