# Can't access windows 10 partition after update to 23.10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I used to be able to access a separate ssd for windows, but after updating to Ubuntu 23.10 it gives me the following error :

> Unable to access location
> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/abdelrahman/2A907C5D907C3185: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Also there is another partition on that ssd that is accessible without issues.

How to solve this issue without formatting the other drive ?

[image: image of the error msg]

Comment: Is it an NTFS filesystem? Can you try mounting it manually: create a mountpoint `mkdir ~/my_mount` then mont it specifying FS `sudo mount -t ntfs3 /dev/sdb1 ~/my_mount`

Comment: Some helpful information that you might want to include in your question are the output of `findmnt --fstab` and `sudo file -Ls /dev/sdb1` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem usually occurs due to bad clusters, dirty states or due to a missing helper program.

The basic fix for missing helper program is to install the following:

```
sudo apt install nfs-common
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Still if you are unable to fix the problem, `ntfsfix` might help fix the partition

The ntfs-3g package contains the ntfsfix utility(This usually comes preinstalled). If not,

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

Then try to fix the partition using the following commands

Change the partition based on your system. In your case the **634 GB Volume** is `/dev/sdb1` as displayed in the screenshot you provided. In order to fix that particular partition, run the following

```
sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdb1
```

`-b` tries to fix bad clusters and `-d` to fix dirty states.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't quiet get what helper program you mean? ... NTFS filesystems are supported by the kernel ... Please see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.17/_sources/filesystems/ntfs3.rst.txt ... And rushing to run checking/fixing tools on filesystems you don't investigate first might lead to data loss/corruption, so be careful please.

Comment: sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdb1

this fixed the issue, thank you very much.

Comment: @Raffa Earlier on my system, NTFS partitions were marked as fuse filesystem and were mounted using fuse. In most of the cases it displayed the same error as displayed on the above screenshot. I had to manually change fuse from mounting the filesystem. Permissions won't take effect on a fuse filesystem. The first two commands helped me in fixing the issue and mounting ntfs using default ntfs-3g driver. As of my knowledge ntfsfix is widely used to fix ntfs partition in linux with very minimal data loss chances. Correct me if my understanding is wrong, I'm still in the learning phase. Thank you!

Comment: @ArjunKShibu FUSE is not the case anymore, in fact it may cause problems with recent kernels  and `ntfsfix` schedules a future check on Windows that might override changes made on Ubuntu, so not that safe ... I have added an answer that I hope will clear things up.

Answer (score 3):

### Helpful technical information

##### `ntfs-3g` is not the thing anymore

The FUSE based `ntfs-3g` implementation of reading/writing NTFS filesystems in Ubuntu is no more advised and is [**now obsolete in favor of the current native NTFS kernel driver/module NTFS3**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1413349).

##### `ntfsfix` is not your first go to tool

It dosn't fully fix anything, but rather, mainly, removes the safety markers that trigger the safety measures on Ubuntu so that the affected partition will not be mounted or will be mounted in read-only (*to protect your data*) and therefore allowing you to make changes to that filesystem that might damage your Windows installation and cause data loss on both sides, Ubuntu and Windows, in regards to that filesystem ... Quoting from [`man ntfsfix`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/ntfsfix.8.html) (*emphasis is **NOT** mine*) it says:

> **ntfsfix** is **NOT** a Linux version
> of chkdsk.  It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal
> file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

... which means that neither your newly written data (*from Ubuntu*) on that filesystem nor the preexisting data (*from Windows*) is considered safe/fixed yet, but rather pending a filesystem check the next time you boot to Windows ... and quoting from [`man ntfs-3g`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html) (*emphasis is mine*) it says:

> On computers which can be dual-booted into Windows or Linux, Windows has to be fully  shut
> down  before  booting into Linux, otherwise the NTFS file systems on internal disks may be
> left in an inconsistent state **and changes made by Linux may be ignored by Windows**.

##### Why is this happening

In dual boot systems with Windows managing those filesystems, this issue is, in the majority of cases, is caused by Windows hibernation which saves the current running session to disk or Windows fast boot/reboot feature enabled which will do the same i.e. saving current running session to disk which might include unsaved user data or system operations and changing/"fixing" that filesystem in such state from within Ubuntu is not recommended to prevent data loss and/or filesystem corruption … Therefore, the default system response of refusing to mount such filesystem or at most mounting it in read-only mode that you see on Ubuntu is because such unstable filesystem state is detected and it’s not safe enough to be mounted as a read and write filesystem.

##### What to do then?

Check NTFS filesystems from within Windows and not from within Ubuntu and then make a clean shutdown from Windows and not a hibernation or a reboot with fast reboot feature enabled.

Comment: Much appreciated! Thanks for the information!

Comment: yeah fast boot was actually on, also worth mentioning that when booting to windows last few weeks every boot it was scanning for drive errors and doing the auto repair thing, but never stopped doing it even when I let it finish the repair, but after I ran `sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdb1` from ubuntu it stopped