# how to fix this location could not be displayed error on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount

I'm pretty new to `Linux`, and I have 2 normal `NTFS` partitions everything was working fine and I can easily mount and use both portions from `Ubuntu Linux`. but one day I was deleting a huge file from one of the mounted partitions, by mistake I used the dismount command on this partition while the file was being deleted, whenever I try to remount it, I get this error :

```
this location could not be displayed :
sorry couldn't display all the content of "data": Error when getting information for file "the_path_to _the_file_it_was_being_deleted"
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1492900/968501

Answer (score 0):

Try ntfsfix  (libntfs-3g)

Usage: ntfsfix [options] device

Attempt to fix an NTFS partition.

```
-b, --clear-bad-sectors Clear the bad sector list
-d, --clear-dirty       Clear the volume dirty flag
-h, --help              Display this help
-n, --no-action         Do not write anything
-V, --version           Display version information
```

For example: ntfsfix -b /dev/sda6