# Mounted drive appearing empty in Kubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu

Just a quick overview of system:

Dual boot Kubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 (Kubuntu is primary)

1 nvme SSD with 3 partitions (Ubuntu boot; Windows boot; and a shared partition).

My issue:

I only actually just needed to use windows last night, and I noticed the shared partition is appearing empty in windows.  When I booted into Linux this morning the partition appears empty now too and is mounted as fuseblk.

When I look at the properties it says that I've used about 30GB (which is accurate), how do I recover these files?  I've had a read around and people say "just copy the files", but I can't even access them in order to even copy them.

Comment: There are cases where changes made by Linux on an NTFS filesystem may be ignored by Windows … Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/1492976 … in which case avoiding  mounting such filesystem in RW mode and considering safe data recovery options in read only mode is advised.

Comment: @Raffa thanks, I had a look at that and tried that, but it still appears empty in both windows and linux despite saying that there is data and folders in there.