ntfs partition got stuck in hibernation (I believe) and I need to recover it or fix it somehow
TL;DR: The drive is hibernated? I cannot delete the hiberfil-file on the drive, as it is read only.
Ok, I'm not the most tech-savvy guy. So I'm trying my best to explain what I believe happened:
I had windows installed on a 1TB nvme drive along with a Linux system. I decided to get rid of the Linux System as I was not using it. The drive was partitioned into 4 parts:
16mb unallocated | 100 mb EFI Partition | 250 gb for MX Linux | 750 NTFS for Windows.
I used a software called Aoemi Parition assistant to expand the drive.
1. Deleted the MX-Partition
2. Expanded the System-Partition
After the computer rebooted, I could not boot into Windows anymore. I've tried troubleshooting it for hours, with my limited knowledge...
I found lots and lots of guides on how to repair windows bootloader... but that might not be important for my question.
The interesting part is this: I used the Windows boot media to "repair computer" and found out, with DISKPART that the partition was still there, I could read it's files...
So, next step. I downloaded Ubuntu and started a live session. I was able to mount the partition, and even read, note: Read-Only, the files. I copied the files/contents of the partition using the cp command. I also created a backup of the partition using the dd command. Specifically: bs=4M into an .img file.
I installed windows onto another drive. The NTFS partition in question is not accessible in Windows, I get this: Access Denied- Error.
The img file is also not mountable in Windows, I get the same error. J:\ is not accesible.
The partition is read-only. I did some research on how I could repair NTFS-partitions on Linux and found this: (I'm posting along with the output)
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/D80E31580E3130BC$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p2
Mounting volume... Hibernated non-system partition, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Hibernated non-system partition, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/D80E31580E313

So, long story short, TL;DR: The drive is hibernated? I cannot delete the hiberfil-file on the drive, as it is read only.
How can I proceed?

You might want to try the -b and -d flags like sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/nvme0n1p2 ... Also, please see https://askubuntu.com/q/1492900 for useful related info.

I got it, here is the output Mounting volume... OK Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully. Checking the alternate boot sector... OK NTFS volume version is 3.1. Going to un-mark the bad clusters ($BadClus)... No bad clusters...OK NTFS partition /dev/nvme0n1p2 was processed successfully.  - I still cannot use it on Windows. Access Denied!

windows problem. use windows to fix it. ... if you don't have windows format the disk into ext4. and restore  a backup.

I can access the partition now in Linux and I have made a backup. The data is save. I would like to make it bootable again if possible.

Run CHKDSK /F from Windows, not from Linux. Always use the native OS for that OS's filesystems.

we do not support windows on askUbuntu, Only answers based off Ubuntu are accepted.

If the correct answer is "use a different tool" then tough. This time, it is.

I should have mentioned that I already did that. Multiple times in fact. It did not find errors. But it did not help as well. I was hoping I could use the power of Linux to somehow repair that partition.

Yes, you should have mentioned that. It's important. How did you run it, from Windows booted from that volume, or using a Windows recovery console from a bootable medium?

Windows on the volume in question is NOT BOOTABLE, which is the very issue... So, I booted from a Windows-Installation on another physical disk.

You still are not answering my question clearly and completely. We are trying to help you here, not play guessing games. Is this a full install of Windows on a local drive, or is it a installation disk on a bootable USB? The latter is what you want.


Go to Microsoft.com and download a Windows ISO. Free and safe. Also download Ventoy. Format a USB key with Ventoy. Copy the ISO onto it.


Boot from the key. Pick Windows. Pick Recovery Console.


Run CHKDSK /F on the drive, as I said.


Only once the drive passes checks as clean try to remove the file from Linux, as root.


