# How to rename multiple files and folders recursively that include * and other symbols not valid for filenames/folders?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, rename

For somewhat reason, my Ubuntu Mate 20.04 let me include `*` and other symbols apparently not valid for a filename or folder. But now I need to copy a lot of archives (like 15,000) to another PC. I don't know how to make a script for this, so I need help with it to let me rename everything inside a folder and the name of that folder also, example:

Folders:

```
701*math**2nd

100*eng**1st

etc...
```

Archives:

```
800-task**201.xls

508-ok*10**300.doc

etc...
```

I just need to remove the characters, exchanging the `*` for a `_` or just remove the character from the name of file, because file manager doesn't let me copy them to an external HDD.

**EDIT: This worked! https://askubuntu.com/a/1302061/1661703

Comment: `*` is a perfectly valid character for file names (if you are using EXTx file system format). The _only_ invalid characters are `/` and NUL. However, if you are trying to store files with `*` and other special characters not valid on an NTFS file system, then you have to replace these. For more info see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names

Comment: I didnt know that, so in this case I need to remove these characters so I can copy them to a NTFS filesystem

Comment: If your external disk is just empty (that is, it will be used only to transfer files) *and* your target PC is also Linux, I would recommend formatting your external disk as EXT4 (and *not* NTFS or some variant of FAT).

Comment: I need to transfer those files to a windows Pc, so I still need to convert them

Comment: This worked: https://askubuntu.com/a/1302061/1661703

Comment: you could install Krusader with Krename, Tools, Search , save to listbox,  then File, Multirename, Find and Replace, Add   , * to _ ... what I cannot do is search, or filter the results, for only files with an * in them, though if all satisfy that, then select all to krenam, or select manually. one advantage here is being able to see the renames before applying them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rename` command with recursive shell globbing from the parent directory containing all your directories and files that you need to be renamed like so:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 'y/\*/_/' **/*
shopt -u globstar
```

Or (*to avoid a `Argument list is too long` error*) with `find` and `rename` from the same parent directory like so:

```bash
find -exec rename -n 'y/\*/_/' {} \+
```

The option `-n` is for dry-run … Remove it when satisfied with the output to do the actual renaming.

**Additional `raname` syntax**:

- To change each multiple sequence of `*`(*e.g. `**` or `***` etc.*) to a single `_`, use:

  ```
  rename -n 's/[\*]+/_/g'
  ```
- To match and substitute multiple different characters(*e.g. `*`, `?` and `:` etc.*), use:

  ```
  rename -n 's/[\*\?\:]+/_/g'
  ```
- To just remove the matching characters from the names, use empty substitution string like so:

  ```
  rename -n 's/[\*\?\:]+//g'
  ```

**Notices**:

- Please notice that due to directories being renamed as well(*if their names contain matching charackters e.g. `*`, `?` or `:` etc.*), some file paths already passed to `rename` as arguments might change during the process which will result in the error:

  ```
  Can't rename ...: No such file or directory
  ```

  preventing them from being renamed all at once so you need tor re-run the rename command until you get no errors anymore.
- Please also notice that if two or more similar file/directory names share the same path and match different matching characters(*e.g. `file**one`, `file??one` and `file:one` etc*) then they will all be renamed to the same filename(e.g. `file_one`*) resulting in only the first name of its kind(*file/directory`) being renamed and the others will result in the error:

  ```
   ... not renamed: ... already exists
  ```

  Therefore, in which case you will need to change the substitution character/s in the rename command in order to rename those remaining files/directories e.g. double `_` like so:

  ```
  rename -n 's/[\*\?\:]+/__/g'
  ```

Comment: I get an error: "Argument list is too long"

Comment: @Silver I updated the answer for that.

Comment: @Silver I apologize ... There was an unintended mistake(*typo*) in the answer but now corrected ... I apologize again :-)

Comment: The rename operation is a risky one. There is always a chance of name collision, because NTFS is case sensitive and you have to map more than one (forbidden) characters onto a single (`_`) character. Windows has also name restrictions on complete file / directory names.

Comment: @FedKad Thank you for your feedback :-) Added your notes to the answer ... unfortunately as you know such a process can not simply and cleanly be done in one shot.